# UDP in Seattle vs Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, udp, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

This piece of code runs fine under Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   //var    IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
   begin
     idudpclient1.host := '127.0.0.1';
     idudpclient1.port := 1234;
     idudpclient1.Binding.Port := 1234;
     idudpclient1.Binding.Bind;
     idudpclient1.Send('Hello');
   end;
```

Running the exact same code under Delphi 10 Seattle 32 bit windows 
gives socket runtime error 10022: Invalid argument, 
and then
Could not bind socket, address and port are already in use.

Any ideas?

Best regards
Thomas Riedel

Comment: On which line does it fail? Have you stepped through your own code as well as the Indy code? I don't use UDPClient but does the .send require a string or pchar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Indy 10, when you access the `Binding` property, the socket gets created *and bound* if it is not already.  So you are trying to call `Bind()` on a socket that is already bound.

The "Invalid argument" error is raised when the underlying socket API `bind()` fails.  Per MSDN's [`bind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) documentation:

> WSAEINVAL
>  
>   An invalid argument was supplied.
>
> **This error is returned of the socket `s` is already bound to an address**.

`TIdSocketHandle.Bind()` calls `TIdSocketHandle.TryBind()`, and `TryBind()` catches the "Invalid argument" error, so you should only be seeing it if you are running your code in the debugger.  The "Could not bind socket" error is Indy's own error that `TIdSocketHandle.Bind()` raises if `TryBind()` fails.

You should not be setting `Binding.Port` directly, or calling `Binding.Bind()` directly, at all.  Use the `TIdUDPClient.BoundPort` property (and optionally also `TIdUDPClient.BoundIP`) instead:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
//var    IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
begin
  IdUDPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  IdUDPClient1.Port := 1234;
  //IdUDPClient1.BoundIP := '127.0.0.1';
  IdUDPClient1.BoundPort := 1234;
  IdUDPClient1.Send('Hello');
end;
```

When `TIdUDPClient` allocates its socket, it will call `Bind()` for you, assigning the `BoundPort` to the `Binding.Port` (and `BoundIP` to `Binding.IP`).

The reason your code worked in Delphi 7 is because you were using Indy 9 (or earlier) instead of Indy 10.  In those earlier Indy versions, accessing the `Binding` property only allocated the socket, it did not also bind the socket, thus you were able to bind it manually.  That is no longer the case.